# How can I assign a list to another list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to do something like this in Groovy:

```
List<MyObject> list1 = getAList();
```

How can I assign a list to other list in groovy without having to iterate through the list I want to assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work as you have it (assuming `getAList` returns a List)...

Or do you mean you want a new list containing the same elements as the list returned?

If that's the case, you can do

```
List<MyObject> list1 = getAList().collect()
```

Or

```
List<MyObject> list1 = new ArrayList<MyObject>( getAList() )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to concatenate the elements of one array/list with another, you can do the following:

```
def ar1 = ["one","two"]
def ar2 = ["three","four"]
def ar3 = ar1 + ar2
return ar3
```

This should produce

```
["one","two","three","four"]
```